# Bonita BPM connector shows drop down list in random order. xml tree-map

Tags: java, xml, bonita

I am trying to make a new connector in Bonita BPM but the select widget shows the entries at random. the xml treats it as a tree-map and i cannot do anything about it. My xml looks like :

```
<select>
<labelId>ZZZZZ</labelId>
<setter reference="/connector/inputs/setter[2]"/>
<values class="tree-map">
<entry>
<string>XXXXXX</string>
<string>XXX</string> 
</entry>
<entry>
<string>YYYYYY</string>
<string>YYY</string> 
</entry>
...
```

Is there something that I can do to order the pop-down alphabetically or so?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Bonita are you using? It works in v6 and v7.

Comment: 5.9.1 Thanks a lot i did not realize it could depend on the version

Comment: Yes, connector structure changed with v6 and was maintained in v7. I am sorry but there is not much you can do to fix your issue other than migrating to a more recent version. However, given the effort it represent, it is not worth it for just this.